# Interactive Processing Sketch over UDP Connection

Tags: java, c, sockets, networking, processing

I'm writing an interactive Processing sketch to control a laser projector by sending messages over UDP to the Ether Dream DAC. I have successfully compiled and run the C driver provided by the Ether Dream creator, and studied the protocol described here:
http://ether-dream.com/protocol.html

I am using the UDP library for Processing, and have successfully read the status signal that the DAC broadcasts every second. I can seemingly send messages (described in the DAC protocol) to the DAC using the udp.send() but I never get the acknowledgement message back.

```
udp = new UDP( this ,7654 );
```

When I initialize my UDP object this way I am able to read the broadcast message.

but...

```
udp = new UDP( this ,7654, "192.169.0.101");
```

When I initialize it this way I get the message:

```
opening socket failed!
> address:192.169.0.101, port:7654 [group:null]
> Can't assign requested address
```

I have also tried port 7765, which is also mentioned in the documentation but with the same result.

The UDP library opens a connection like this:

```
// open a new socket to the specified port/address
// and join the group if the multicast socket is required
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    InetAddress host = (ip==null) ? (InetAddress)null: addr;
    if ( !addr.isMulticastAddress() ) {
        ucSocket = new DatagramSocket( port, host );    // as broadcast
        log( "bound socket to host:"+address()+", port: "+port() );
    }
```

The C driver provided by the Ether Dream creator which runs successfully opens a connection to the DAC like this:

```
struct etherdream_conn *conn = &d->conn;
memset(conn, 0, sizeof *conn);

// Open socket
conn->dc_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (conn->dc_sock < 0) {
    log_socket_error(d, "socket");
    return -1;
}

unsigned long nonblocking = 1;
ioctl(conn->dc_sock, FIONBIO, &nonblocking);

struct sockaddr_in addr = {
    .sin_family = AF_INET,
    .sin_addr.s_addr = d->addr.s_addr, .sin_port = htons(7765)
};

// Because the socket is nonblocking, this will always error...
connect(conn->dc_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (int)sizeof addr);
if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
    log_socket_error(d, "connect");
    goto bail;
}
```

The repository for this driver can be found [here](https://github.com/j4cbo/j4cDAC/tree/master/driver/libetherdream/).

Why can't I establish a connection to the DAC through the Processing UDP library? How can I modify the Java implementation of the UDP library so that it matches the C driver which can successfully connect to the DAC?

Comment: Make sure that "192.169.0.101" is your local IP address. Try the same with "localhost"

Comment: Did that and it seemed to work better, but then when I tried to send a message using udp.send("?","192.168.0.103",7654); I get the same can't assign address error... :/

Comment: Did you use own IP address or localhost?

Comment: used localhost when initializing the udp connection

Comment: Try to use your own IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Broadcast from the DAC happend over UDP on 7654

Communication with the DAC happens over TCP on port 7765

The following java code will locate the Etherdream DAC using UDP and establish a TCP communication with the Etherdream DAC.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Etherdream implements Runnable {

    public Etherdream() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Etherdream laser = new Etherdream();
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum State {
        GET_BROADCAST, KEEP_ALIVE_PING,
    }

    // https://ether-dream.com/protocol.html

    enum Command {
        PREPARE_STREAM(0x70), BEGIN_PLAYBACK(0x62), QUEUE_RATE_CHANGE(0x74), WRITE_DATA(0x64), STOP(0x73),
        EMERGENCY_STOP(0x00), EMERGENCY_STOP_ALTERNATIVE(0xFF), CLEAR_EMERGENCY_STOP(0x63), PING(0x3F),

        ACK_RESPONSE(0x61), NAK_FULL_RESPONSE(0x46), NAK_INVALID_RESPONSE(0x49), NAK_STOPCONDITION_RESPONSE(0x21);

        final byte command;

        private Command(int cmd) {
            command = (byte) (cmd & 0xFF);
        }

        public byte[] bytes() {
            return new byte[] { command };
        }

        public byte getCommand() {
            return command;
        }
    }

    enum DACStatus {
        IDLE(0x01), PREPARED(0x02), PLAYING(0x03);

        final byte status;

        private DACStatus(int cmd) {
            status = (byte) (cmd & 0xFF);
        }

        public byte[] bytes() {
            return new byte[] { status };
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        State state = State.GET_BROADCAST;
        InetAddress etherdreamAddress = null;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("state " + state);
            try {
                switch (state) {
                    case GET_BROADCAST: {
                        // Wait and get broadcast using UDP

                        try (DatagramSocket inSocket = new DatagramSocket(7654)) {

                            // get broadcast
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                            DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                            inSocket.receive(response);
        
                            /*
                             * struct j4cDAC_broadcast { 
                             *   uint8_t mac_address[6];
                             *   uint16_t hw_revision;
                             *   uint16_t sw_revision;
                             *   uint16_t buffer_capacity;
                             *   uint32_t max_point_rate;
                             *   struct dac_status status;
                             * };
                             */
        
                            byte[] broadcast = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, response.getLength());

                            etherdreamAddress = response.getAddress();
        
                            if (etherdreamAddress != null) {
                                state = State.KEEP_ALIVE_PING;
                            }

                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case KEEP_ALIVE_PING: {
                        // Send ping using TCP port 7765
                        
                        try (Socket socket = new Socket(etherdreamAddress, 7765)) {
 
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                            Command cmd = Command.PING;
                            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                            output.write(cmd.bytes());
                            
                            /*  
                             *  struct dac_response {
                             *    uint8_t response;
                             *    uint8_t command;
                             *    struct status dac_status;
                             *  };  
                             */
                            
                            byte[] dac_response = input.readNBytes(3);

                            // make sure we got an ACK
                            if(dac_response[0]!=Command.ACK_RESPONSE.command){
                                state = State.GET_BROADCAST;
                                break;
                            }

                            // make sure we got the response form the PING command
                            if(dac_response[1]!=cmd.command){
                                state = State.GET_BROADCAST;
                                break;
                            }
                            /*
                             *   struct dac_status {
                             *       uint8_t protocol;
                             *       uint8_t light_engine_state;
                             *       uint8_t playback_state;
                             *       uint8_t source;
                             *       uint16_t light_engine_flags;
                             *       uint16_t playback_flags;
                             *       uint16_t source_flags;
                             *       uint16_t buffer_fullness;
                             *      uint32_t point_rate;
                             *      uint32_t point_count;
                             *   };
                             */
                            byte[] dac_status = input.readNBytes(20);

                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        state = State.GET_BROADCAST;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* If any IO error occour
                 * for any reason such as
                 * network cable disconnect
                 * then try locate the Etherdream DAC again
                 */ 
                state = State.GET_BROADCAST;
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a complete example that can locate the Etherdream DAC and plot a circle at https://github.com/xranby/EtherdreamDACJavaProcessing